# CGRect.offsetBy Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, view, cgrect

How do I rewrite the code below?

```
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
```

> 'Offset' has been replaced by 'offsetby'

When I replaced it with the so called "solution":

```
self.view.frame = CGRect.offsetby(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
```

I receive an error:

> "Instance member 'offsetBy' cannot be used on type 'CGRect'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

Comment: Are you working with Xcode 9.x? Swift 4? If so, please define what `movement` is.

Comment: @dfd Xcode: 9.2 & Swift 4

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to call `offsetBy` on an instance of a `CGRect`.

```
self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
```